# Dialog primefaces with src dynamic

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

actually i have a problem using Dialog with content dynamic, when i presed a commandButton i want appear a Dialog, but the content's dialog doesn't appear

XHTML

```
</p:treeTable>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{showEn.displaySelectedNode}" oncomplete="PF('dialogWidget').show()"/>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog appendTo="@(body)" id="dialog" widgetVar="dialogWidget">
        <ui:include src="#{showEn.dialog}"/>
    </p:dialog>
```

Java

```
public void displaySelectedNode(){
if(!dialogs[0].equals("-")){
        this.dialog="addEn.xhtml";
    }else if(!dialogs[1].equals("-")){
        this.dialog="addCu.xhtml";
    }else if(!dialogs[2].equals("-")){
        this.dialog="addTa.xhtml";
    }
}
public String getDialog() {
    return dialog;
}
public void setDialog(String dialog) {
    this.dialog = dialog;
}
```

Comment: you are not updating the dialog region !, and i guess that showEn is a Bean ? what is his scope?

Comment: when i put update="dialog" the dialog doesn´t appear, and you right the showEn is a bean and is sessionscoped.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog tag must be wrapped, then update the wrapper instead.

```
<h:panelGroup id='wrapper' >
     <p:dialog appendTo="@(body)" id="dialog" widgetVar="dialogWidget" 
dynamic="true" /* given that the src is evaluated during the build phase, 
the use of dynamic content offer a second update
    */>
            <ui:include src="#{showEn.dialog}"/>
     </p:dialog>
</panelGroup>
<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{showEn.displaySelectedNode}"     
        oncomplete="PF('dialogWidget').show()" update="wrapper" />
```

the problem with this solution is that the content will not change in case the dialog is already loaded,

i suggest try this solution :

java

```
private boolean urlChanged;
public boolean isUrlChanged(){
    if (urlChanged){
        urlChanged = false; 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void displaySelectedNode(){
 urlChanged = true;
   if(!dialogs[0].equals("-")){
        this.dialog="addEn.xhtml";
    }else if(!dialogs[1].equals("-")){
        this.dialog="addCu.xhtml";
    }else if(!dialogs[2].equals("-")){
        this.dialog="addTa.xhtml";
    }
}
```

xhtml

```
<p:dialog appendTo="@(body)" id="dialog" widgetVar="dialogWidget" 
dynamic="false" /* no need for that */>
       <h:panelGroup id='wrapper' >
            <p:remoteCommand name="updateAgain" update="wrapper"/>
            <c:if test="#{showEn.isUrlChanged}"><script>updateAgain();</script></c:if>
            <ui:include src="#{showEn.dialog}"/>
       </panelGroup>  
</p:dialog>

<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{showEn.displaySelectedNode}"     
        oncomplete="PF('dialogWidget').show()" update="wrapper" />
```

Comment: doesn't work, when i pressed the button the dialog appear empty, i print the dialog value and print the correct value, but doesnt appear in src value.

Comment: i haven't achieved that works, basically, i want wich when in a treetable a node was selected the variable "dialog" change, this variable will be the value of src in the dialog. The dialog appear when button Add was pressed.

Comment: i try to implement you code, but doesnt work, i print (System.ou.print) the value of dialog when i pressed the button Add, but just appear once, ande the dialog doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've achieved wich works, the problems is the primefaces version i was working with primefaces 5, the correct version for this throuble is primefaces version 4. Thanks anyway. ;)